# Execute C# code on remote machine

Tags: c#, remote-access

i have a piece of code which i want to execute on remote computer. I am not getting how to do that. Like if i want to execute command given below on remote machine how to do that.

```
 Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

it is just an example, like i want to execute whole code on remote machine with libraries.

if you are going to answer for getting processlist as

```
SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_Process");
using(ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =new ManagementObjectSearcher(manScope, selectQuery))
```

i already know that , please save it. is there any way to execute whole code after connecting to scope.

Comment: just that I get it right: you want to sent some code-piece to some other machine, let it execute there and get the result back? And all this without having to set up something on the remote machine? ... So basically you are asking of how to setup a bot-net?

Comment: @CarstenKönig actually the code is same which i want to send. just parameters will differ. but you got that right. i want that code to execute on remote machine. like i want to execuete  uint dwSessionId1 = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() and                        WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId1, ref hUserToken).. on remote machine. when i tried it from my local machine it returned me my local machines attributes.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Are you saying you have all your code on machine A and you want to say, "OK machine B, run this code that I have on machine A". You can't do that. You might try something like psexec https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx.

Comment: @aquinas i dont want to use external tools. and i have explained in above comment what i want to do.

Comment: are you aware that if you manage this you will need some administrative rights on the remote machine? Usually you just write some kind of server-app that you can call and that the administrator will have to install and run on the target system

Comment: @kaustubh93, this seems like an XY problem to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378. Instead of asking about executing code on a remote machine, can you explain what the *end* goal is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @aquinas i want to launch a application on remote machine with its GUI in  currently logged in desktop session.

Comment: @CarstenKönig while remotely logging in I am using username password of administrator account of that remote machine..will that do..??

Comment: How about just using `at` / `schtasks` ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313565?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: @aquinas i thought the same. but problem is, schtasks will work on vista and windows 7 . for windows 8 and server 2012 it wont work.

Comment: That's not true. schtasks works on Windows 8 and 2012.

Comment: @aquinas sorry i didnt knew that. read somewhere that schtask dont work work with it so they added jt.exe. it it works then well and good. btw i need an favour. do you know how to use schtask in powershell to schedule a task.

Comment: @aquinas will you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007829/scheduling-task-in-windows-2008-with-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting list  of process on remote machine just enter name of remote machine in brackests..

```
      Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses(Remotemachine);
```

for reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's no overload for `GetProcesses()` on a remote machine, but if you're just looking for a particular process name, you could try the `GetProcessesByName(string, string)` overload, which allows you to pass a machine name as the second parameter.

See MSDN for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/725c3z81(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, please note that you are not actually executing your command on a remote computer, but rather making a request to a remote computer.  In order to do that, you would want to look into WCF (Windows Communication Foundation; start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You could run a service on the remote computer and have a client on your local computer consume that service.  The client might send a message like "Get me all the processes!" and the service would return a list of processes after running `Process.GetProcesses()` on the remote machine.

If you're asking about a way to execute arbitrary code on a remote machine without any special tooling or libraries, there is none (or rather, there are at times but they're considered major security vulnerabilities and get patched when found).

Alternatively, it's possible to make use of the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) to do what you're trying to achieve.  It's possible to make use of this programatically, but you might have a hard time limiting it to just one application.

Comment: it was an example. actually i want to exeute  code on remote machine with  different parameters. like i want to execute uint dwSessionId1 = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() and WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId1, ref hUserToken) on remote machine. when i tried it from my local machine it returned me my local machines attributes.

Comment: Right.  You'd need to write a service that executes that code running on the remote machine and then have that service return the values to your local machine.

Comment: okay. but what if when i try my code from a Client and machine is not running that service at that time. secondly is there any other way without running that service.  and also initially do i have to go to each computer and set up that service. or i can do set up service remotely.???

Comment: You'd have to set up the service on that machine.  If you're a network administrator and your network has facilities to do so, you might be able to remotely install software (or require users to do so).  But this is sounding more and more like you're trying to create security problems...

Comment: yes i know. actually i want to launch an application on remote machine with its GUI in currently logged in users desktop. i dont want to use any external tools.

Comment: Then look into the Remote Desktop Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, what about .NET remoting?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

1. use PowerShell to run remote commands: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.2)

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName your-computer-name -Credential your-user-name
Set-Location "C:\your\code\location.exe"
.\location.exe
```

2. the NuGet package SSH.net: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883237/how-to-run-commands-on-ssh-server-in-c)

```
//using Renci.SshNet; //Make sure the Nuget package is install and compatible
using (var client = new SshClient("your-computer-name", "your-user-name", "your-password")) 
{
    client.Connect();
    client.RunCommand("cd .\your\code\");
    SshCommand sc = client.RunCommand("location.exe");
    MessageBox.Show(sc.Error);
    MessageBox.Show(sc.Result);
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

3. initiate remote control via c#: [link](https://nipunadilhara.medium.com/opening-remote-desktop-using-c-7615dd4e9228)

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", "/C mstsc /v:\"your-computer-name\"");
process.Start();
public static string DoProcess(string cmd, string argv)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = $" {argv}";
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            //p.StartInfo.Verb = "RunAs";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.Dispose();

            return output;
        }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30316979)