# scheduling task in windows 2008 with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0, scheduler

i want to schedule task in windows 2008 r2 with powershell. i used

```
   $username = "BUILTIN\Users"
   $TaskName = 'kakaka'
   $t=1
   $TaskRun = "$PSHome\powershell.exe  Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\v.exe' -ArgumentList '/a' -Verb runas -WindowStyle Normal"
   $start = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($t).ToString("HH:mm") 
   schtasks /create /ru $username /tn $Taskname /tr $TaskRun /sc once /st $start /f
```

on using above script i got an error "schtasks.exe : ERROR: The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range."  same script worked fine on windows 7.

Comment: Part of this issue you might be having is `$Taskname` will not be quoted when it expands on the call. try putting quotes around the variable: `/tn "$Taskname"`

Comment: @Matt no man thats not problem. checked.

Comment: Why are you running an executable via PowerShell in a scheduled task? Would running the executable with highest privileges (`/tr '"C:\v.exe /a"' /rl highest`) not suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is issue of password which is resolved in below post :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/fe7345ea-b037-469b-b425-17d5fee28e91/windows-server-backup-wont-schedule

```
SYMPTOMS

When you try to change the run as user for a scheduled task in Server 2008, The task is currently configured to runas SYSTEM. Using the following command line he receives the error. 

c:\>SCHTASKS /CHANGE /TN TestTask /RU TestUser 

SCHTASKS prompts the user for a password for the runas user account. After entering the password it displays the following error. 


"ERROR: The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range. (52,4):Task:" 


The task's runas credentials have not changed. 


RESOLUTION

To avoid this error you must add the /RP option with an "*". The new command line will look like this: 

c:\>SCHTASKS /CHANGE /TN TestTask /RU TestUser /RP * 

SCHTASKS prompts the user for a password for the runas user account. After entering the password the task is updated without error.
```

Comment: yes...now task can be scheduled using  option " /rp * " but it is not running. dont know why.

Comment: this is susccessfully bypassing error. but not running task. do you know why and did above correction worked for you..??