# Renci SSH.NET: How to create symlinks?

Tags: c#, sftp, symlink, ssh.net

I am currently uploading files to a unix server using SFTP using Renci SSH.NET, and it works fine. However, I now would like to upload files to a "Symlink container", and then create a symlink in another directory pointing to these files. Is that possible? I haven't found a class to manage symlinks, so how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `SftpClient.SymbolicLink` method.

```
public void SymbolicLink(string path, string linkPath)
```

Note that the meaning of the paths is a mess. The most common SFTP server, the OpenSSH, is buggy and uses the paths in a wrong order. Many other SFTP servers follow the bug for a compatibility. But not all. So you have to test which order is used by your servers.

See

- https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=861
- http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4080

Comment: Thank you Martin, this works, however, what if I want to delete the link (not the real target, only the link) again? SftpClient.Delete throws an exception ("Failure").

Comment: It should work. Post a new question with a full code and more information.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with SSH.net and I don't have found something about symlinks. However I found that SSH.net supports custom commands therefor you can write the Linux command (I think that it's **ln**) to create the symblink.

In this url you can get an example about how to use a custom command with SSH [How to run several commands with SSH.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891135/how-to-run-several-commands-with-ssh-net)

Maybe if you need to create a lot symlinks, you can create a class or you can download the source code and add a new method.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful, especially for commands not supported by SSH.NET directly.