# SSH.NET is not executing command on device

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

I'm trying to send a simple command over SSH using SSH.NET. Even the simplest test code fails. Here is a snippet.

```
using (var ssh = new SshClient("ip", port, "username", "password"))
{
    ssh.Connect();
    while (true)
    {
        var result = ssh.RunCommand("AT").Execute(); 
        Console.Out.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

The `AT` command should echo back OK but doesn't. Instead I receive a custom timeout message issued by the SSH target. I see the device name in the timeout message which corresponds to the prompt it uses and from that i can conclude that the login works (also tested with various SSH programs) but the command itself is not executed. I tried adding `\n` and `\r\n` to the commands but to no results. What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1: 
output from result is `\r\nCommand Line Interface\r\nDeviceName> Custom idle timeout` I think the line endings are converted to Windows ones by Visual Studio.

Edit 2:
Using Plink `plink.exe username@ip -pw password "AT" > log.txt` results in the same output as Visual Studio. Plink waits till timeout and terminates and  `log.txt`contains `\r\nCommand Line Interface\r\nDeviceName> Custom idle timeout`.

Using PuTTY I see that

```
Using username "username".
username@host's password:

Entering character mode
Escape character is '^]'.

Command Line Interface
DeviceName>
```

is written before you can start entering commands. Might it be that the command is entered before the host is ready to receive it and as a result the command hangs until some reaction comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server obviously does not support the SSH "exec" channel that is used behind the SSH.NET `SshClient.RunCommand` method and PLink's `plink.exe command` syntax.

Or actually it does support it, but incorrectly. It seems to start an interactive session (a shell), instead of executing the command.

To confirm this assumption, try this with PLink:

```
echo AT| plink username@ip -pw password > log.txt
```

If that works, you may need to use the `SshClient.CreateShell` (SSH "shell" channel") and write the command to its input stream, instead of using the `SshClient.RunCommand`. While this is generally a [wrong approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30883237/850848#44797940), you need to take this approach due to your broken server.

---

*A similar question for Python/Paramiko:

[Executing command using Paramiko exec_command on device is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30603219/850848)*.